# How do I deploy a release build to an iPhone emulator for MAUI?

Tags: ios, emulation, maui, release

I'm using the latest version of VS 2022 for Mac. I can successfully deploy debug and release builds of my app to an iPhone device but can only deploy a release build to a device, not an emulator. This definitely puts a kink in my testing capabilities. When I try to do a release build for iPhone 14 iOS 16.2, I get the following error message:

```
Can not execute "/[Insert Solution Path]/bin/Release/net7.0-android/[AppName.dll]". The selected execution mode is not supported for .NET projects.
```

I replaced my specific info with the stuff in "[]".

I have no idea why an android-specific path is being referenced when doing an iPhone build.

When the build process stops, I do see what looks like a completely built package under bin/Release/net7.0-ios/iossimulator-x64 within Visual Studio. However, nothing gets deployed to the emulator.

So, I have a few questions...

1. Should I be able to deploy a release build to an iPhone emulator?
2. If the android reference is expected, what else could the problem be?
3. If that android reference is not expected, I'd love some direction on what might be causing the error.
4. Is it possible to deploy the release package to the emulator manually?

Comment: I just discovered that I don't always get the error message. Sometimes, the build process executes successfully but the package doesn't deploy to the emulator.

Comment: I confirm this happens on current VS 2022 Mac, with a newly made project from Maui template. I UNCHECKED the Android target, and get the more reasonable "Can not execute ...Release/net7.0-ios/iossimulator-x64/MyProjectName.exe. The selected execution mode is not supported for .NET projects." So the mention of Android is just a flaw in the error message you got; the important point is that it isn't wanting to launch to emulator. You could make an issue at `github maui issues`.

Comment: Thanks @ToolmakerSteve. I’ll probably report the issue. I say “probably” because I’m getting tired of spending time reporting MAUI bugs. It seems like VS builds the Release package but doesn’t deploy it. Do you know how to manually deploy a package to an iPhone emulator?

Comment: Submitted this as issue #14979 for MAUI on github.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a Release configuration, you can run the app by clicking on "Start Without Debugging" under the "Debug" menu tab:

[image: "Start Without Debugging" option under the "Debug" menu tab]

The reason why it doesn't work is, when using the play button...

[image]

... underneath, it will run the app the same way as if you had clicked on "Start Debugging":

[image]

However, debugging is NOT supported in Release configuration!

This is just a workaround to a known bug by Visual Studio teams.
More information can be found in this [ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/The-selected-execution-mode-is-not-suppo/10358767).

Comment: Thank you for this @Kapusch. If others are wondering, this process both deploys and runs the Release build on the simulator. I was surprised to find that it did the deployment in addition to running the app.

Comment: Thanks a ton!!! This along with changing my signing cert to "Developer (Automatic)" and provisioning profile to "Automatic" worked for me to get the app to build in release and deploy to my device.

Comment: How did you change the cert to "Developer (Automatic)"? can you share the details? @gadildafissh

Comment: @Divyesh, I clicked the dropdown in the provisioning section for iOS, and changed the option.